# PL/SQL SQL*Plus Statement Ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sqlplus

I'm doing a trigger on my Oracle database, here's the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER send_telegram_message
AFTER INSERT ON EVENT_LOG
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  GROUP_IDS VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.EVENT_ID AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL THEN

    SELECT ID_GRUPO INTO GROUP_IDS
    FROM V_EVENT_TELEGRAM 
    WHERE V_EVENT_TELEGRAM.EVENT_ID = :NEW.EVENT_ID;

    TELEGRAM_BOT(GROUP_IDS,:NEW.DESCRIPTION);
  END IF;
END;
```

When compile I'm getting the following error:

Error(4,3): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
  Error(4,6): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

The problem seems to be with the type of group_ids variable, I've been trying to solve this PLS-00382 issue but I can't.

The "TELEGRAM_BOT()" line is a procedure call that invokes a Java published method:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE telegram_bot (group_ids VARCHAR2, message VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA 
NAME 'TelegramBot.subMain(String,String)';
```

Comment: `IF :NEW.EVENT_ID AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL THEN` is not valid sql syntax.

Comment: The error message is pointing at line 4 (counting from the `DECLARE`, since it's a PL/SQL error), which is the line sagi refers to. And it says *expression* is of wrong type, not a variable, so no idea why you think the type of `group_ids` is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with the triggers. You simply have a syntax error in the following line:

```
IF :NEW.EVENT_ID AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL THEN
```

[`if` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/if_statement.htm#LNPLS01324) and logical operators expect a boolean expression. PL/SQL doesn't have implicit data type conversions to boolean values.

This means `:NEW.EVENT_ID` is not a valid boolean expression so it can't be used with `and`-operator and therefore the compilation fails with:

```
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Essentially your problem can be narrowed down to the following example:

```
declare
  v_foo number;
begin
  -- compilation fails because a number (or any other non-boolean
  -- data type) is not a boolean expression.
  if v_foo
  then
    null;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Working examples (compiles fine):

```
declare
  v_foo number;
  function to_boolean(p_x in number) return boolean is
  begin
    return p_x > 0;
  end;
begin
  -- a function returns a boolean value
  if to_boolean(v_foo)
  then
    null;
  end if;

  -- a > operator returns a boolean value
  if v_foo > 0
  then
    null;
  end if;

  -- is null operator returns a boolean value
  if v_foo is null
  then
    null;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER send_telegram_message
AFTER INSERT ON EVENT_LOG
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  GROUP_IDS VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.EVENT_ID IS NOT  NULL AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL THEN

    SELECT ID_GRUPO INTO GROUP_IDS
    FROM V_EVENT_TELEGRAM 
    WHERE V_EVENT_TELEGRAM.EVENT_ID = :NEW.EVENT_ID;

    TELEGRAM_BOT(GROUP_IDS,:NEW.DESCRIPTION);
  END IF;
END;
```