# PL/SQL If statement, cursors, and a record set. How to use an IF statement after I use the Cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am wondering if I am going about this the right way.
My main issue that compiler gives is for this line
`IF SELECT 1 FROM works WHERE an_employee.employee_name IN works.manager_name THEN`

> Error(17,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe

What I am trying to do is use a cursor that detects the first condition if they work in a company that is in that city.  In this example in my table it will give 2 companies, and about 7 or 8 employees.  Then I put that into my variable an_employee.  What I am trying to do is use that employee then to see if they are a manager from my manages table which has multiple rows/tuples.  Not everyone is a manager.  How can I see if my `employee_name` is in the list of `manager_name`?

Do I declare another cursor for a manager and then do a nested loop?
Can I use my existing cursor and do a select query to get the list of managers from the table `manages.manager_name`?  If I do that, how can I use it in the IF statement as my condition?

```
-- Give all employees that work in a company located in city X 
-- a Y percent raise if they are managers and 
-- a Z percent raise if they are not a manager
-- X, Y, and Z will be the three parameters for the stored procedure.
-- Build / compile a stored procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE give_raises(X company.city%TYPE, Y NUMBER, Z NUMBER) IS
    an_employee works.employee_name%TYPE;

-- cursor declaration
cursor Cursor1 IS
  select works.employee_name
  from works
  where works.company_name IN (select company_name from company where city = 'London');

BEGIN
  SELECT manager_name INTO managers FROM manages;
  OPEN Cursor1;
  LOOP
    FETCH Cursor1 INTO an_employee;
    EXIT WHEN Cursor1%NOTFOUND;
    -- is a manager give Y percent raise
    IF SELECT 1 FROM works WHERE an_employee.employee_name IN works.manager_name THEN
      update works
      set works.salary = works.salary + (works.salary * Y)
      where works.employee_name = an_employee.employee_name;
    ELSE  -- is not a manager give Z percent raise
      update works
      set works.salary = works.salary + (works.salary * Z)
      where works.employee_name = an_employee.employee_name;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE Cursor1;
END;
```

Also you should know.  I am using Oracle, Oracle Sql Developer and the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly you are trying to identify whether an employee is manager or not based on thatsalary is computed. Hope below snippet helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE give_raises(
    X company.city%TYPE,
    Y NUMBER,
    Z NUMBER)
AS
  managers PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR an_employee IN
  (SELECT works.employee_name
  FROM works
  WHERE works.company_name IN
    (SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE city = 'London'
    )
  )
  LOOP
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO managers
    FROM manages m
    WHERE m.manager_name = an_employee.employee_name; 
    -- is a manager give Y percent raise
    IF managers <> 0 THEN
      UPDATE works
      SET works.salary          = works.salary + (works.salary * Y)
      WHERE works.employee_name = an_employee.employee_name;
    ELSE -- is not a manager give Z percent raise
      UPDATE works
      SET works.salary          = works.salary + (works.salary * Z)
      WHERE works.employee_name = an_employee.employee_name;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

If works on a logical condition and does not support Select statements in the condition.

You need to rework your code like this

```
SELECT count(*) 
INTO v_value
FROM works 
WHERE an_employee.employee_name = works.manager_name;

IF v_value = 1 THEN
   --do some stuff
ELSE
   --do some other stuff
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you, so helpful.  I'm going to go work on it.  Yes, that  makes much more sense lol

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is essentially the same than e.g. in [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36330346/272735) posted yesterday. PL/SQL [`if` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/if_statement.htm#LNPLS01324) expects a *boolean expression* not a [query result set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00603).

A good practice is to encapsulate the query to a function returning a suitable value.

**Example:**

```
SQL> !cat so53.sql
declare
  function is_foo_1(p_foo in varchar2) return boolean is
    v_exists number;
  begin
    select count(*)
      into v_exists
      from dual
     where dummy = p_foo
       and rownum = 1
    ;
    return
      case v_exists
        when 1 then true
        else        false
      end;
  end;
  function is_foo_2(p_foo in varchar2) return number is
    v_exists number;
  begin
    select count(*)
      into v_exists
      from dual
     where dummy = p_foo
       and rownum = 1
    ;
    return v_exists;
  end;
begin
  -- is_foo_1 returns a boolean value than is a valid boolean expression
  if is_foo_1('X')
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('1:X');
  end if;

  if not is_foo_1('Y')
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('1:not Y');
  end if;

  -- is_foo_2 returns a number that is not a valid boolean expression (PL/SQL
  -- doesn't have implicit type conversions) so one have to use an operator
  -- (in this example `=`-operator) to construct an explicit boolean
  -- expression
  if is_foo_2('X') = 1
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('2:X');
  end if;

  if is_foo_2('Y') = 0
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('2:not Y');
  end if;
end;
/
```

**Example run:**

```
SQL> @so53.sql
1:X
1:not Y
2:X
2:not Y

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```